# VBA subscript out of range and Excel's default variables

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post on here and I have very little formal training in coding, so this is probably a very easy problem.

I'm running into an error 9, VBA Subscript out of range, when running macros defined by the code below. 
Specifically, it is the Sub Select_Last() function. Excel does not like the subsequent expression, however if this is used on its own in a separate Excel file then it works fine.

I think the problem is that Excel's default variable (Activesheet etc) are conflicting with each other. But I am not sure how to remedy this. The other subs work fine. Can anyone help? Thank you.

```
Public lastsheet As String

Sub Select_Last()
   Sheets(lastsheet).Select
End Sub

Sub Protect()
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      Sheets(i).Protect
   Next i
End Sub

Sub UnProtect()
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      Sheets(i).UnProtect
   Next i
End Sub

Sub SelectUnlockedCells()
   Dim WorkRng As Range
   Dim OutRng As Range
   Dim Rng As Range
   On Error Resume Next
   Set WorkRng = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For Each Rng In WorkRng
     If Rng.Locked = False Then
        If OutRng.Count = 0 Then
          Set OutRng = Rng
        Else
          Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
        End If
     End If
   Next
   If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng.Select
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

The other functions work OK.

Comment: Where and how do you assign a value to `lastsheet`? And where is that variable declared (which module)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all `On Error Resume Next` hides errors, but they still occur. I suggest you to code without using it if you are learning. Second, you define `Public lastsheet As String` but in your code you never assign a value to this variable. Default value in a string variable is `""` and it equals to nothing ( a null value). It's kind of empty. So when you do `Sheets(lastsheet).Select` you are telling Excel to select a worksheet named *null value* and that can't be. All worksheets in a workbook **must** have a name

Comment: Hi, James, please also keep in mind that your "For" Loop in "Sub SelectUnlockedCells()" has no variable indicated after the "Next" statement. There are minor mistakes in your code that lead me to think that it could use some rethinking in the overall structure, such as the comment @Rory has indicated.

Comment: Use Option Explicit, and compile before running !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you. The lastsheet value is assigned viaPrivate Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
lastsheet = Sh.Name
End Sub

Comment: I'm not a coder. The numerous exclamation marks may indicate your frustration with my lack of knowledge, but that is the reason I am asking the questions I am. I have no coding experience aside from what I can gather on sites like this. The vast majority of my job is nothing to do with coding, or computers. Please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Public lastsheet As String

Sub Select_Last()
    lastsheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name
    Sheets(lastsheet).Select
End Sub
```

The key issue is to assign a value to a variable before using it.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but selects the last sheet in the workbook, whereas I want to select the last active sheet. I had actually missed some of the code before. Lastsheet is defined as the previously deactivated sheet Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
lastsheet = Sh.Name
End Sub